# Can't start Django 1.7.1 development server

Tags: django, django-1.7, manage.py

I migrated my Django app from 1.4.3 to 1.7.1
I got it working for a short while
but now every time I try to run the development server it gets stuck on:

```
C:\Users\DAVID\Documents\TinyTap-web\tinytap>python manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

System check identified some issues:

WARNINGS:
?: (1_6.W001) Some project unittests may not execute as expected.
        HINT: Django 1.6 introduced a new default test runner. It looks like this project was        generated using Django 1.5 or earlier. You should ensure
. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.6/#new-test-runner for more information.

System check identified 1 issue (0 silenced).
```

the localhost is not working , also tried with other IP/ports = same results.

I could get rid of this warning by adding `TEST_RUNNER = 'django.test.runner.DiscoverRunner'` to the settings file, but still development server is not running

Comment: That is a warning, not an error, and wouldn't stop the dev server from running.

Comment: what is the error after you "fixed" the warning? what is the output of `./manage.py runserver` ?

Comment: sax- it's 
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it was related to migrations and "CircularDependencyError".

After deleting the database , and the migration folders and running `manage.py migrate` 
I was finally able to `runserver`

Answer (score 0):

Trying creating a new project

```
django-admin.py startproject mysite
```

If it works then there's problem with the current project you're trying to run. (You'll need to give us more information for us to help)

Comment: Thanks James, a new project does work. its manage.py is identical to mine, i copied modified and used its wsgi.py and added WSGI_APPLICATION = 'wsgi.application' in the settings, no results

Comment: Okay, you have two options, either upload your project to github and provide a link or migrate your files over to the new project you created.